# Scaling animation or Texture Atlas on libgdx

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, textures, scaling

I forgot to set the proper size of my frames in photoshop so now the animation of my character is huge, is there a way I can scale the texture atlas or animation using methods just like `.setSize();`.I mean scaling just like sprites and textures.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be much better off scaling them in photoshop.

Scaling them will mean that you're using up way more texture memory than you need to, and will potentially add complications in other areas too.\

If you really want to do it, simply scale draw the TextureRegions that you get back from getKeyFrame() with a scale applied.

Comment: No, it's very possible. Just scale the texture that you get back from getKeyFrame. I'm just advising against it.